# SQL Server 2014 Profiler Login Time Out Expired

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-profiler

I am able to connect to my SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and run queries, but when I try to open SQL Server Profiler and run a trace, I am getting the below error. Can you tell me how to resolve this issue?

[image]

SQL Server Configuration manager:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen on profiler only? Did you try setting up a connection from ssms?

Comment: yes its happening only for the profiler, ssms is working fine for me

Comment: Did you sort this. Im having same issue.